# Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given Error in LMS theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently installed LMS theme on wordpress. I m getting this error after turning debugging on:

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php on line 417.

Code:

```
function next_token() {
    $matches = null;

    /*
     * aye the magic
     * we're using a single RegExp to tokenize the block comment delimiters
     * we're also using a trick here because the only difference between a
     * block opener and a block closer is the leading `/` before `wp:` (and
     * a closer has no attributes). we can trap them both and process the
     * match back in PHP to see which one it was.
     */
    $has_match = preg_match(
        '/<!--\s+(?P<closer>\/)?wp:(?P<namespace>[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*\/)?(?P<name>[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*)\s+(?P<attrs>{(?:(?:[^}]+|}+(?=})|(?!}\s+\/?-->).)*+)?}\s+)?(?P<void>\/)?-->/s',
        $this->document,
        $matches,
        PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,
        $this->offset  // this is line 417
    );
```

Comment: Well, `$this->document` is an array, as the error suggests. `preg_match` wants a string there.

Comment: so what should i do here.. what should i change in this code

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Having the same issue in WP version 6.3.1 with a different theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. I had to downgrade to WP core 5.1.1